# dynamic array vs normal array to find Kaprekar's Constant using C language

Tags: c, loops

The following program print the number of time to reach to [Kaprekars 
Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_(number))
I don't understand why it runs on infinite loop when I use normal array 
while it works when I use dynamic array as I wrote in comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define size 4

void KaprekarsConstant(int num) {
    //int *arr;
    int j, i, temp, sorted, counter = 0, rev;
    while (num != 6174) {
        int arr[3] = { 0 };
        //arr = (int*)calloc((size - 1), sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; num != 0; i++) {
            arr[i] = num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            for (j = i - 1, temp = arr[i]; (temp < arr[j]) && (j >= 0); j--) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            }
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
            j++;
        }
        for (i = 0, sorted = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sorted = arr[i] + (sorted * 10);
        }
        for (i = size - 1, rev = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
            rev = arr[i] + (rev * 10);
        }
        num = abs(rev - sorted);
        counter++;
    }
    //free(arr);
    printf("%d\n", counter);
}

int main(void) {
    KaprekarsConstant(2111); //print 5
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most, if not all of your `for` loops access `arr` out of bounds (you have an array of size 3 but are accessing the 4th element). You are invoking *undefined behavior* in both versions

Comment: `int arr[3]` ==> `int arr[size]`

Comment: this such a silly mistake I thought I only need 4 index since I looking for four  digits but the second version works somehow see [link]( https://ideone.com/0xyuAr) whitch make thing the  overflow is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You code has undefined behavior in both cases because you access and modify `arr` beyond its boundaries: `arr` is defined or allocated with a size of `3` but you access and modify `arr[3]` which is the fourth element.

It is highly error prone to redefine the identifier `size` as a macro. You should at least use `SIZE` or `NUMBER_SIZE`.